# AndroidSensorsDriver

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone explain me **step by step** how to communicte an android device and computer over ros. I am new on ROS. I just try to send info from android device to computer. the tutorial says,

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://IP:11311/

roscore

After that, I type the http://IP:11311/ on android device

But it doesn't work.

I dont want to know detail of android_core etc. so I download the application on my phone.  After i start the application and type IP, phone is shut down.

Is there any other way to communicate android device and computer. Or how can I fix this application error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135036/androidsensorsdriver/) by [lifetime](https://answers.ros.org/users/10156/lifetime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-03**:
Are you replacing IP in the directions with the IP address of your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both IPs are same and which is computer's IP. I solved my problem. I use Samsung Galaxy s2 and the android version is 4.1.2

The last version of android sensors driver application is not working for me. So I download previous version.(0.3) Now its works :)

---

Originally posted by [lifetime](https://answers.ros.org/users/10156/lifetime/) with karma: 33 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0